# Help with Factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need two numbers that multiply to get $-20$ and add to get $1$. I'm doing a quadratic functions problem and I can't find the answer to this part of the question.

It started out as finding the zero of the equation by factoring. The equation was $g(x)=2x^2+x-10$. I set it equal to zero, $x^2+x-20=0$. Now I have to factor but I can't find a way to. If it's prime, I don't know how to answer the main question.

$a \times b = -20$  and
$a + b = 1$

Comment: Write down all of the factors or 20: 1, 20; 2, 10; 4,5. Do you see any pair that can give you one when added or subtracted?

Comment: $$-4\cdot5=-20 , -4+5=1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\  $ Since you know $\,\color{#0a0}{a+b}\ $ and $\color{#c00}{ab}\,$ you also know the coefficients of the polynomial $\,(x-a)(x-b) = x^2 -(\color{#0a0}{a+b})x + \color{#c00}{ab},\,$ so you can find the roots  $\,a,b\,$ by the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

As Amzoti instructed in the comments, simply write down all the factors of $20$ and one must give you what you desire, else the quadratic cannot be factored..

$1\times 20 \space \text{either}\space 1+20, -1+20, 1+-20, -1+-20\\\\
2\times 10 \space \text{either}\space 2+10, -2+10, 2+-10, -2+-10\\\\
4\times 5, \space \text{either}\space 4+5, -4+5, 4+-5, -4+-5\\$

It should be clear that the factors $1\space \text{and}\space 20$ and $2\space \text{and} \space10$ will **not** give you $1$. So let's focus on $4\space \text{and}\space 5$.

$4+5=9\\ -4+5=1\\ 4+-5=-1\\ -4+-5=-9$

Since $-4, 5$ when added give you $b=1$ and when multiplied give you $-20$, then $g(x)$ factored is

$$g(x)=2x^2+x−10=(x-4)(x+5)$$

Alternately you can use the **quadratic formula**:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

You have $a=2$, $1$ and $c=-10$ so you can plug these respective values into the formula to get the values of $x$.